# Django form - using variable from database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following form which is working perfectly:

```
# coding=utf-8

    from django import forms
    from straightred.models import StraightredTeam
    from straightred.models import UserSelection

    class SelectTwoTeams(forms.Form):

        cantSelectTeams = UserSelection.objects.filter(campaignno=102501349)

        currentTeams = StraightredTeam.objects.filter(currentteam = 1).exclude(teamid__in=cantSelectTeams.values_list('teamselectionid', flat=True))
        team_one = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = currentTeams)
        team_two = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = currentTeams)
```

However, as you can see the campaignno is hard written into the query.  Ideally I would like to select the maximum campaignno from a mysql table and use that as the campaigno instead of the 102501349 as above.  The mysql table and model is as follows:

mySQL table:

```
mysql> desc straightred_userselection;
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| userselectionid   | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| campaignno        | varchar(36)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| teamselection1or2 | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fixtureid         | int(11)              | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| teamselectionid   | int(11)              | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id           | int(11)              | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Django Model:

```
class StraightredSeason(models.Model):
    seasonid = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    seasonyear = models.CharField(max_length = 4)
    seasonname = models.CharField(max_length = 36)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.seasonid

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'straightred_season'
```

I hope this makes sense but if you require any more information then just ask :)

I appreciate any assistance in advance, many thanks, Alan.

Comment: select the maximum campaignno from a mysql table, you want the maximum number depend on how many row in your table now?

Comment: at the moment there are only two but there will be loads.  It was more the principal of how is it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got there in the end :)

I used the following:

```
campaignnoquery = UserSelection.objects.filter(user=349).order_by('-campaignno')[:1]

    for x in campaignnoquery:
        test2 = x.campaignno
```

I can then use test2 as the variable.